# How to make light beam to be super narrow?

Tags: optics, laser, geometric-optics

I am doing a project to use a regular laser beam to be super narrow (25um diameter). I am thinking to use some lens setup to do that. Does any lens setup can make a 5mm diameter laser light source to go down to 25um diameter (1/200 of the original)?

Comment: What about a converging lens and then a collimator? But I don't know if that works for the orders of magnitude you're talking about.

Comment: Perhaps this is more of an engineering question?

Comment: Do you think that I can use a regular microscope to achieve this?

Comment: I am also thinking that if I make the beam very narrow. The energy will be very dense. I might be able to use a 1W laser beam to cut stainless steel.

Comment: The distance the beam can stay collimated is inversely proportional to the diameter of the beam. A 25 um "beam" will start to diverge pretty quickly. So it's important whether you actually need a beam, or if you just want a 25 um spot (for the cutting application you just mentioned).

Comment: Diffraction and lens imperfections limit the size of the focal spot. If you have a 1W laser for this purpose, it is likely a CO2 laser at 10.6um. At this wavelength, lenses are typically ZnSe with an index of refraction 2.7, much higher than in the visible. This makes lenses with gentle curves work well. Lens imperfections are so small that you only worry about diffraction. Google Gaussian Beam for more about this. Companies that make lenses for this purpose should be able to help you. Lasers for cutting steel are often 100W.

Comment: @ThePhoton I want to make a laser milling machine (which is similar to cutting, but need to be able to control the depth of material remove )

Comment: @mmesser314 Why CO2?, when you can buy a solid-state laser module, considerably more powerful than 1W for less than $200.  https://www.ebay.com/i/132465672237?chn=ps

Comment: @besmirched - I guess life has changed since 1985, when I was an optical engineer.

Comment: @GiordanoFearghas: I would be surprised if a 1W laser would cut steel in any kind of bulk, however finely you focus it, although I may be wrong about this.

Comment: indeed @user205719 ,  CO2 wavelength seems far from optimal:
https://www.google.com/search?as_st=y&tbm=isch&as_q=steel+reflectivity+wavelength&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&imgsz=&imgar=&imgc=&imgcolor=&imgtype=&cr=&as_sitesearch=&safe=images&as_filetype=&as_rights=

Answer (score 1):

yes there are ,for example have a look at the [open source light sheet micoscopy project](https://openspim.org/)
Its usually a combination of beam expander, beam collimation, converging lens.
As others noted, the smaller the focus waist, [the faster it increases when out of focus](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/19180/how-can-i-build-a-micrometer-diameter-laser-beam-from-a-common-laser-diode)